# Combining Large Number of Queries into One

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a simple query with 6 fields one of which is price.  In this same query I have and added 15 more as aliases with IFF statements returning a "T" or "F".

```
input_device: IIf([item]="Keyboard","T","F")
```

In the past a separate query would look at the first, find a "T" flag and then sum the price of those records.

```
SELECT Sum(tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown.total_price) AS total_price_sum
FROM tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown
WHERE (((tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown.INPUT_device)="T"));

SELECT Sum(tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown.total_price) AS total_price_sum
FROM tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown
WHERE (((tmp_tbl_cost_breakdown.OUTPUT_device)="T"));
```

There are 14 additional queries like the two just above that give a price total for that category.

Input = $543,984
Output = $343,223
Etc ...

How can I do this with a few queries as possible?

Comment: Looking at that now but I do not think it will eliminate the need for the secondary queries.  It would need to have 15 different fields in the rows which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 (Select .... First Secondary Query) as TC_INPUT_DEVICE,
             (Select .... Second Secondary Query) as TC_OUTPUT_DEVICE,
             (Select .... Third Secondary Query) as TC_PROCESSING_DEVICE,
             Etc
             ;
```

The "TC" is for total cost and is needed or in this case you will get a circular reference error.

No this does not make for less code but it does put it all in one place so that the report is easy.